# How to use Sublime SFTP with multiple Vagrant VMs

Tags: vagrant, sublimetext2, sftp

I have figured out how to use Sublime SFTP with Vagrant. But I constantly am switching between multiple Vagrant VMs and running multiple VMs at once. In order to connect Sublime SFTP to the VM, you have to set the host:

```
"host": "127.0.0.1",
"user": "vagrant",
//"password": "",
"port": "2222",
"ssh_key_file": "/home/jeremy/.vagrant/machines/inspire/virtualbox/private_key",
```

The only problem is the `"port": "222"` field will change depending on when I start up which VMs and how many I am running. So it makes it impossible to use sublime with these VMs with having to reconfigure the sftp_servers file first. Is there any way to permanently assign the port to the VM or a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

in your `Vagrantfile` you can define the ssh port with property `config.ssh.port`